# Creating an Integer LinkedList with ANSI C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I want to make a linked list of integers using structures and memory allocation. There is this error I got that doesn't make much sense to me. From what I know, if you have a pointer `ptr` that points to a structure with variable `x` as its element, then `*(ptr).x` is equivalent to `ptr->x`. However, here the behavior is different:

```
typedef struct
{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
}node;

//create a pointer to a new node containing the entered value
node * newNode(int data)
{
    //create new node and a pointer to it
    node  next;
    node * ptr;

    next.data = data;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    *(ptr) = next;

    return ptr;
}

static node *  head;

int main()
{
    //my goal here is to start creating a linked list with values 1,2,3,4 respectively.
    node * currentNode;
    head = newNode(1);

    *(head).next = newNode(2);  

}
```

If I compile this piece of code I get an error about next not being a member of a structure. However,
 when I substitute `*(head).next = newNode(2)` with `head->next = newNode(2)`  I get a warning only about the incompatibility of the pointer types. I don't understand the difference in behavior nor the source of the errors here. Thanks for the help ahead.

Comment: `(*haed).next` or `head->next`. and need initialize `next.next=NULL;`  or  `node next = {0, NULL};`

Comment: No, `*(ptr).x` is equivalent to `*(ptr.x)` instead of `ptr->x`.

Comment: @ BLUEPIXY : i thought pointers by default once created point to NULL.

Comment: The incompatibility of pointer types (after fixing your precedence issue as the answers say) is because of the structure declaration: You typedef `struct { ... }` to `node`, which contains a pointer to a `struct node`, which is another type than `node`. Change to `typedef struct node { int data; struct node *next; } node;`.

Comment: @ mafso : you were right. I didn't know that this would creat two different struct types.

Comment: _i thought pointers by default once created point to NULL._ : no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` has higher precedence than `*`, so the second expression `head->next` is equivalent to `(*head).next`, not `*(head).next`.

With respect to your second error, that is because your `struct` declaration is missing a tag. You are effectively declaring an anonymous `struct` and then `typedef`ing it to `node`. Here is a corrected declaration which gets rid of the incompatible pointer warning.

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} node;
```

Finally, your `newNode` function can simplified as follows, with the standard library header for `NULL`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

//create a pointer to a new node containing the entered value
node * newNode(int data)
{
    node * ptr;

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
node *head;
```

There is an enormous difference between:

```
*(head).next
```

and

```
(*head).next
```

The first is incorrect; it is equivalent to `*head.next` or `*(head.next)` but `head` is a pointer, not a structure, so the `.` notation cannot be used.

The second is the correct version, equivalent to `head->next`.

The member access operators `.` and `->` bind very tightly, and much more tightly than `*` does.  The behaviour is a simple consequence of the operator precedence levels.

Your `newNode()` function should ensure that the new node is completely initialized. It should set `next.next = 0;` (or `next.next = NULL;`) before assigning to `*ptr` — the parentheses in `*(ptr)` are completely superfluous.